# Bring Git branches in sync

Tags: git-branch, git-merge, git-extensions

We have a Master branch and a Develop branch for our repo. We are supposed to check-in (commit, push) to our Develop branch and then merge that with our Master branch. Then a build is run for the Master branch. I pushed my changes directly to Master (then tagged it), putting Master multiple commits ahead of Develop and now want to bring Develop in sync with Master. What is the best practice to do this? I use GitExtensions and Visual Studio 2015 (am ok doing the operation in either). Do I 'push' Master into Develop or do a check out of remote branch Master and merge with my local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would find it most clear to just check out both branches locally, merge in the changes from your local master to your local develop. Then push your local develop to remote.

Answer (score 1):

The workflow I use works something like this in the scenario you describe:

- Switch to Develop branch
- Fetch All
- Choose last (newest) commit in Master, right click => Rebase current branch on => (commit ID)

If Rebase works successfully you're done. If not, you may need to resolve conflicts or cancel the Rebase and merge from scratch.

The reason for using Rebase is that it maintains a single line of commits thus helping keep everything clear.

For more info on the difference between rebase and merge see:
https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing